# What major figures don't have contemporary historiographers?

Tags: ancient-history, historiography

Are there many, or even any, major figures whose life and achievements have only been described by historians posthumously, or at least the only surviving primary sources about which are dated later than their deaths? Or at least figures whose contemporary-written historiographies have only been discovered relatively recently (i.e. who were known only by posthumous historiography for a long while)?

The question comes from a context of a discussion where someone pointed out that some religious figures' lives were only described posthumously, and another objected that some secular figures had a similar fate, citing Alexander the Great as an example (but Wikipedia seems to indicate that this Alexander's life was described by contemporaries too, making this example invalid). Do such examples exist? Are they common? Is there a general period after which they become more rare/common? Are the written-contemporarily-but-then-lost or only-written-posthumously examples more common?

I'm not seeking a specific/exhaustive list, but a few (preferably some of the most famous/influential) examples would be good for confirming such figures exist, and understanding the approximate height of achievement that can 'get away' with being noteworthy enough to be documented, but not enough to have ubiquitous contemporary sources. If there's more than a few, I'd like to know approximately how common they are.

Comment: Is a "major figure" someone whose deeds were worthy enough to be recorded and lucky enough to have those records survive to today? The problem with these sorts of list questions is that they often descend into a discussion of the relative merits of the figures which clouds the issue and makes a definitive answer difficult to arrive at.

Comment: Perhaps the cut-off point of importance will be fuzzy, but even knowing what sort of figures with only posthumous records are within this 'fuzzy area' would be helpful. E.g. are the biggest such figures on the level of a major conqueror who significantly reshaped political geography (like Alexander or Timujin), on a level of someone who ruled a smaller area but enacted policies with long-term impacts (like Hammurabi), like an inventor (e.g. the creators of Hangul or some American writing systems)?

Comment: @SteveBird The major point of interest is whether secular or mostly-secular figures exist which *are* deemed important in their impact, and are believed to have actually existed (according to historical consensus), and have surviving historiography (or oral tradition treated as equivalent), but whose historiography only originates posthumously.

Comment: The question seems to cover (at least) two scenarios. The first is where the 'major figure' was only considered worthy of record in retrospect and, therefore, their life and achievements were originally documented posthumously. The other is where they were appreciated during their lifetime but those contemporary records were lost (possibly because the historian wasn't notable enough to have their work saved) and, thus, only later histories have survived to today. How can we tell those apart?

Comment: Please revise the question to permit an [Authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401).

Comment: What exactly is meant by "historiography" here? I think the important primary sources on Genghis Khan were written after his death, but there are primary sources that **mention** him and were probably created during his life. Would he count?

Comment: What you are interested in, is a statistics task. Ask ChatGPT, it is good in it.

Answer (score 4):

This applies to most (almost all) historical figures of distant past. Indeed "history writing" really begins with Herodotus, so all historical figures who lived before him belong to this category.

Now about Alexander of Macedonia. His life and activity were really described by several contemporaries, but none of these writings survive. All we have was written many years after his death.

Most of the ancient Greek history that we have was written
centuries after the events, with some rare exceptions like
the Peloponnesian war.

It is even worse with Persian empire, and the states in the Middle east before it. No written histories survive (it is even not clear whether they ever existed). All we know about Persian empire essentially comes from Herodotus and other Greek authors, and this was written much later than the events happened.

This applies to most historical figures of early middle age. For example, the so-called Primary Chronicle is the only written source of the history of ancient Rus (Ukraine). It was written around 1110, and there are no other histories for
the period before this. Same applies to histories of Poland and other European countries.

Comment: For Darius I we actually have a long-ish written source whose *original* has survived until today: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behistun_Inscription

Comment: @Jan: you are right. We  have several inscriptions, besides the books.

Comment: We also have the Biblical texts and Egyptian texts as witnesses to the Persians. It's not solely through the Greeks.